# Как определить, что в текст в CKEditor были внесены изменения?

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, javascript, ckeditor

Пытался сравнивать исходный текст в textarea с CKEDITOR.instances[''].getData(), но опера и ие считают, что эти строки не равны. Есть другие идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В CKEDITOR доступна [обработка событий](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html), в том числе по изменению полей. Попробуйте так

```
var all = CKEDITOR.instances;
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    all[i].on('change', function () {
        /* Необходимые действия */
    });
}
```

Это потребует дополнительного плагина (ссылка на загрузку на странице блога).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Хоть и кривое решение, но все-таки решение...)